# What all permissions are required to view all the tables in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following grant permissions in Oracle database.
**DB_CONNECT,
READ_ONLY_ROLE,
USER_ROLE.**

I am able to connect to database. But not able to view any tables, views and procedures. Is it because of these grant permissions? If so, please let me know what all other grant permissions are required to access all the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'all the tables'

I'm guessing you mean ALL the tables you need, not all the tables in the database.

If you have SELECT ANY TABLE privilege, then you can do exactly that.

If you have SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE you can query the dictionary to see what tables are there, but not necessarly query those actual tables.

See this guide on security. 
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authorization.htm#DBSEG99875

I doubt you need any of these.

what you need is the SELECT privilege granted to you on the TABLES you need to work with. If you are going to work with procedures, you also need EXECUTE privs on them.

Since you are on SQL Developer, it's also possible [you're not looking in the right place](http://%20https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/03/why-cant-i-see-my-tables-in-oracle-sql-developer/).

[image]

The tool by default shows you the tables, views, and pl/sql objects in the schema associated with your login/user.

If you login as user A, but the tables belong to B, you have to drill down into user B from the 'Other Users' section of the connection tree.

Comment: Thanks @thatjeffsmith.  Under my account, no tables are listed. actually I need to have access to 77 tables in database. I hope  the following query will fix it.                            grant select any table to username ;

Comment: Your account has no tables. The tables you need access to are in OTHER accounts. Someone with security privs needs to grant you SELECT on those 77 tables. SELECT ANY TABLE will make the entire database available to you, which might be worse than you not having access to those 77 tables.